# How can I grab rows with max date from Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

and I want to grab for each distinct ID, the row with the max date so that my final results looks something like this:

[image]

My date column is of data type 'object'. I have tried grouping and then trying to grab the max like the following:

```
idx = df.groupby(['ID','Item'])['date'].transform(max) == df_Trans['date']
df_new = df[idx]
```

However I am unable to get the desired result.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### `idxmax`

Should work so long as `index` is unique or the maximal index isn't repeated.

```
df.loc[df.groupby('ID').date.idxmax()]
```

---

#### OP (edited)

Should work as long as maximal values are unique.  Otherwise, you'll get all rows equal to the maximum.

```
df[df.groupby('ID')['date'].transform('max') == df['date']]
```

---

#### W-B go to solution

And also very good solution.

```
df.sort_values(['ID', 'date']).drop_duplicates('date', keep='last')
```

Answer (score 2):

The last bit of code from [piRSquared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53199076/grab-rows-with-max-date-from-pandas-dataframe/53199093#53199093) is wrong.

We are trying to get distinct IDs, so the column used in drop_duplicates should be 'ID'. keep='last' would then retrieve the last (and max) date for each ID.

```
df.sort_values(['ID', 'date']).drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last')
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a generalization of [piRSquared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53199076/grab-rows-with-max-date-from-pandas-dataframe/53199093#53199093):

- `manykey` indicates the keys from which the mapping is desired (many-to)
- `onekey` indicates the keys to which the mapping is desired (-to-one)
- `sortkey` is sortable key and it follows `asc` set to True (as python standard)

  ```
  def get_last(df:pd.DataFrame,manykey:list[str],onekey:list[str],sortkey,asc=True):
       return df.sort_values(sortkey,asc).drop_duplicates(subset=manykey, keep='last')[manykey+onekey]
  ```

In your case the answer should be:

```
get_last(df,["id"],["item"],"date")
```

Note that I am using the `onekey` explicitly because I want to drop the rest of the keys (if they are in the table) and create a mapping.